# Set position of a <div> from data saved in localStorage

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to learn how to use localStorage.

Partly imitating, I have written html that generates a page with a few tiles that you can drag and drop around the page.

For example

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function drag_start(event){
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
    var str = (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left")) - event.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top")) - event.clientY)+ ',' + event.target.id;
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text",str);
    event.stopPropagation();
    }

    function drop(event){
    var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text").split(',');
    var dm = document.getElementById(offset[2]);
    dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0],10)) + 'px';
    dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1],10)) + 'px';
    localStorage.setItem(dm.id,dm.style.left);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }

    function drag_over(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }

  </script>
```

I think that with a line like the one above beginning with "localStorage" I can save in `localStorage` the position after the drop. [The current line is just a mock example. Later, when I understand these things, I will actually store the position, or the offset.]

The part that I am confused is about how to retrieve the position from `localStorage` when the page is being loaded.

Say, that I am going to have one of the tiles being

```
<div id="tile3"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag_start(event)">
    <a href="http://www.link.somewhere">
          Link
    </a>
</div>
```

I can say that the tile has `style="position:absolute"` and then I would need to retrieve the offset from `localStorage` and set as a property of the `div`.

But how to do this last part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## for the saving you use this javascript command:

(assuming thePosition is an array with two values (x and y position))

```
localStorage.setItem("position", JSON.Stringify(thePosition));
```

on the pageload you can do something like this (assuming you use jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var position = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("position"));

  $('#the-divs-id').css({'left': position[0], 'top': position[1]});
});
```

edit: added JSON stringify/parse for the array

If you want to use no jquery:

```
window.onload = setDiv();

function setDiv(){
  var position = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("position"));
  document.getElementById(the-divs-id).style.left = position[0];
  document.getElementById(the-divs-id).style.top = position[1];
}
```

edit: the looping question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // loops trough all divs with the-class
  $('.the-class').each(function(){
    // get the id from the current div
    // and get the corresponding position from local storage
    var id = $(this).attr('id'),
        position = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(id));
    // sets the css values for the current div
    $(this).css({'left': position[0], 'top': position[1]});
  });
});
```

Comment: I see. `(document).ready` is the key. Is that like an event that rises when the page is loaded (read)? The second line sets the property. Would it be too much to ask to write how would it be that line if written to loop through all `div`'s with certain class?

Comment: I added the loop answer to my answer above. But be aware, that you need to use jquery to use it like provided.

Comment: Interesting. I get the logic now. Well, I don't know what is jQuery. But I will google about it.